# Trying to turn daily info into date ranges in one row

Tags: sql, hiveql

I have a table that is updated every day even if no data has changed. The columns of interest are Effective Date, ID, Status. Instead of having a record for each day I would like date ranges. ID, Status, StartDate, Enddate.

I tried to create a table with a Dense Rank using Dense_Rank Over(Partition by Id, Status order by Effective Date). Then I was going to take Min and Max of effective date using the dense rank but the rank isnt coming out like I thought it would like this:

```
Date.      ID.    Status.  Rownum.
10/01/2021 Abc123 InActive 1
10/02/2021 Abc123 InActive 1
10/03/2021 Abc123 Active 2
10/04/2021 Abc123 Active 2
10/01/2021 Def456 InActive 1
10/02/2021 Def456 InActive 1
10/03/2021 Def456 Active 2
10/04/2021 Def456 active 2
```

But it doesnt. Looking for ideas on how to do this.
edit:

In the end, I want to have a table like:

Id.           Status.      BeginDate.    EndDate

Abc123  inactive.   10/01/2021 10/02/2021

Anc123  Active.      10/03/2021 10/04/2021

Comment: Is that data your input, current output, or desired output?

Comment: That is what i was trying to get to. The first 3 columns are just the data straight out of the table. The last column is what I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

This is a question of linear segmentation.  In your case, your linear measure is time.  Here's how I do this in SQL Server.  Your mileage may vary.  I have added some additional input to demonstrate handling some edge cases.

```
declare @MyTable table (
    [Date.] date not null,
    [ID.] varchar(6) not null,
    [Status.] varchar(10) not null
)

insert @MyTable
values 
  ({d '2021-10-01'}, 'Abc123', 'InActive')
, ({d '2021-10-02'}, 'Abc123', 'InActive')
, ({d '2021-10-03'}, 'Abc123', 'Active')
, ({d '2021-10-04'}, 'Abc123', 'Active')
, ({d '2021-10-05'}, 'Abc123', 'Active')
, ({d '2021-10-06'}, 'Abc123', 'InActive')
, ({d '2021-10-07'}, 'Abc123', 'Active')
, ({d '2021-10-08'}, 'Abc123', 'InActive')
, ({d '2021-10-09'}, 'Abc123', 'InActive')
, ({d '2021-10-01'}, 'Def456', 'InActive')
, ({d '2021-10-02'}, 'Def456', 'InActive')
, ({d '2021-10-03'}, 'Def456', 'Active')
, ({d '2021-10-04'}, 'Def456', 'Active')

;
with a as (
    select lag([ID.]) over(order by [ID.], [Date.]) as IDPrior
    , [ID.]
    , lead([ID.]) over(order by [ID.], [Date.]) as IDNext
    , lag([Status.]) over (order by [ID.], [Date.]) as StatusPrior
    , [Status.]
    , lead([Status.]) over (order by [ID.], [Date.]) as StatusNext
    , [Date.]
    , row_number() over (order by [ID.], [Date.]) as 'RowNum'

    from @MyTable
)
, b as (
    select *
    , CASE
        WHEN RowNum = 1
            THEN 'BEGIN'
        WHEN IDPrior <> [ID.]
            THEN 'BEGIN'
        WHEN StatusPrior <> [Status.]
            THEN 'BEGIN'
        ELSE 'Continue'
      END as SegmentBegin
    , CASE
        WHEN [ID.] <> IDNext
            THEN 'END'
        WHEN [Status.] <> StatusNext
            THEN 'END'
        WHEN RowNum = max(rownum) over ()
            THEN 'END'
        ELSE 'Continue'
      END as SegmentEnd
    
    from a
)
, c as (
    select [ID.]
    , [Status.]
    , [Date.]
    , case when SegmentBegin = 'BEGIN' then [Date.] end as BeginDate
    , case when SegmentEnd   = 'END'   then [Date.] end as EndDate

    from b

    where SegmentBegin = 'BEGIN'
       or SegmentEnd = 'END'
)
, d as (
    select [ID.]
    , [Status.]
    , [Date.]
    , BeginDate
    , case when EndDate is null and lead([ID.]) over (order by [ID.], [Date.]) = [ID.] then lead(EndDate) over (order by [ID.], [Date.]) else EndDate end as EndDate
    
    from c
)
, e as (
    select [ID.]
    , [Status.]
    , [Date.]
    , BeginDate
    , case when EndDate is null then lead(EndDate) over (order by [ID.], [Date.]) else EndDate end as EndDate
    
    from d
)

select [ID.]
, [Status.]
, BeginDate as 'BeginDate.'
, EndDate

from e
    
where BeginDate is not null
order by [ID.]
, [Date.]
```

Output:

| ID. | Status. | BeginDate. | ENDDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Abc123 | InActive | 2021-10-01 | 2021-10-02 |
| Abc123 | Active | 2021-10-03 | 2021-10-05 |
| Abc123 | InActive | 2021-10-06 | 2021-10-06 |
| Abc123 | Active | 2021-10-07 | 2021-10-07 |
| Abc123 | InActive | 2021-10-08 | 2021-10-09 |
| Def456 | InActive | 2021-10-01 | 2021-10-02 |
| Def456 | Active | 2021-10-03 | 2021-10-04 |

Comment: Sorry, the status can repeat is why I need the row number to seperate different instances of the same status. So someone could be active and inactive several times.

Comment: That's why your question should include enough example data to handle edge cases.